# Finding Max with Lambda Expression in Java

Tags: java, lambda, max, java-8

This is my code

```
    List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(1,2,4,3,5).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Integer maxInt = ints.stream()
                              .max(Comparator.comparing(i -> i))
                              .get();

    System.out.println("Maximum number in the set is " + maxInt);
```

output:

```
Maximum number in the set is 5
```

I cannot make distingues between two `i` in below section of my code

```
Comparator.comparing(i -> i)
```

can anyone be kind and explain the difference between two `i`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The method `Comparator.comparing(…)` is intended to create a `Comparator` which uses an order based on a property of the objects to compare. When using the lambda expression `i -> i`, which is a short writing for `(int i) -> { return i; }` here, as a property provider function, the resulting `Comparator` will compare the values itself. This works when the objects to compare have a *natural order* as `Integer` has.

So

```
Stream.of(1,2,4,3,5).max(Comparator.comparing(i -> i))
.ifPresent(maxInt->System.out.println("Maximum number in the set is " + maxInt));
```

does the same as

```
Stream.of(1,2,4,3,5).max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
.ifPresent(maxInt->System.out.println("Maximum number in the set is " + maxInt));
```

though the latter is more efficient as it is implemented as singleton for all types which have a natural order (and implement `Comparable`).

The reason why `max` requires a `Comparator` at all, is because you are using the generic class `Stream` which might contain arbitrary objects.

This allows, e.g. to use it like `streamOfPoints.max(Comparator.comparing(p->p.x))` to find the point with the largest `x` value while `Point` itself does not have a natural order. Or do something like `streamOfPersons.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge))`.

When using the specialized `IntStream` you can use the natural order directly which is likely to be more efficient:

```
IntStream.of(1,2,4,3,5).max()
.ifPresent(maxInt->System.out.println("Maximum number in the set is " + maxInt));
```

---

To illustrate the difference between “natural order” and a property based order:

```
Stream.of("a","bb","aaa","z","b").max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
.ifPresent(max->System.out.println("Maximum string in the set is " + max));
```

this will print

> Maximum string in the set is z

as the natural order of `String`s is the lexicographical order where `z` is greater than `b` which is greater than `a`

On the other hand

```
Stream.of("a","bb","aaa","z","b").max(Comparator.comparing(s->s.length()))
.ifPresent(max->System.out.println("Maximum string in the set is " + max));
```

will print

> Maximum string in the set is aaa

as `aaa` has the maximum *length* of all `String`s in the stream. This is the intended use case for `Comparator.comparing` which can be made even more readable when using method references, i.e. `Comparator.comparing(String::length)` which almost speaks for itself…

Comment: what do you mean natural order? can you break it down with a sample?what do you mean it compares value to itself? can u break it down with a sample?

Comment: so in this case i -> i is kind of redundant ?

Comment: Yes, as said, it does the same as `Comparator.naturalOrder()`. So for `IntStream` you can even omit the `Comparator` and achieve the same.

Comment: i posted my answer as a question, so could you take a look at it and share your thought with me? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399181/for-loop-using-lambda-expression

Answer (score 5):

This function (note `->` is for closures and not to be confused with `=>` which is for comparison)

```
i -> i
```

just means you need to compare the entire object as it is. i.e. if I have an `i` you need to compare `i`

A less trivial example might be

```
max(Comparator.comparing(i -> -i))
```

which will give you the minimum  or

```
max(Comparator.comparing(i -> Math.abs(100-i))
```

gives you a value which is farthest from 100.

```
max(Comparator.comparing(i -> i.toString()))
```

which will give you the maximum comparing as a String i.e. "9" > "10" as a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56159/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-peter-lawrey).

Comment: `=>` is comparison, `->` is a closure.

Comment: I suggest you look at the examples here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: how can i print out the two i in console?

Comment: @KickButtowski There is only one `i`.  The first defines the input, the second refers to the output.

Comment: can you please show me a tutorial that just talked about this issue that I have plz

Comment: how they are the same? if they are the sane why we compare them together?

Comment: @KickButtowski Do you mean the oracle tutorial on Lambdas I linked to a few comments back? ;)  Say these words " `->` is NOT a comparison ".  I have said this twice now.

Comment: the tutorial just talks about this issue. can you put a diagram in your answer to show the relation between two i i-> i plz

Comment: @KickButtowski If you can think of a diagram which would help, I will add it.  It really is very simple, in fact it could hardly be simpler and still be a closure.  Don't assume it is doing more than it is.

Comment: digram like to show one to one relation ship in the set. you know what happened? I had a example that use track -> track.getName , it is kind of make sense but i->i is hard to digest.

Comment: @KickButtowski it's almost too simple to see what point there is in it being there. It is hard to find the purpose of something effectively does nothing by design.

Comment: Just recall that `i -> i` is a short writing for `(int i) -> { return i; }`. By looking at the longer form it should become clear what happens…

Comment: @holger so I got it but can you explain what happen to i inside the function so at the end we end up with i as our return value?

Comment: @Kick Buttowski: nothing happens to `i`. The specified function is only used to determine the *ordering property* for the `Comparator`. If the specified function returns just the value itself it implies that the natural order of the values is used. This is obsolete as `Comparator.naturalOrder()` would do the same. But if you return `-i` instead it would reverse the order. And if you use `i -> Integer.bitCount(i)` it would sort `int` numbers by their bit count.

Comment: @Holger see your explanation is so clear that even my mother can understand it. Could you please post up your explanation with enough detail so I can accept as my answer? please explain it in the way that novice programmers in this case can understand the point like compact tutorial :)

Comment: @Holger so this natural ordering is kind of redundant here?

Answer (score 0):

`Comparator.comparing` expects a function which maps the source object to the value which actually gets compared - in your case, as you don't want to pre-process the value to be compared, `i` is simply mapped to itself.

Comment: can you either explain more or provide me a source so I can read about it?

Comment: Which part of my answer didn't you understand?

Comment: Comparator.comparing expects a function which maps the source object to the value which actually gets compared -

Comment: can you add a diagram to show the relationship of two I i->i

Comment: the two `i` are identical - `Comparator.comparing` expects a function to be applied on every input element and as the function `i -> i` describes that you take every input and return itself as an output, the values to compare are *not* transformed.

Comment: so I got this, but what is gonna compare to what? isn't i compare to i? why we need to compare i to i when they are the same thing? can u understand my confusion?

Comment: may be my issue is that I don't think functional?

Comment: You don't compare `i` to `i`, you compare every object of the list to every other using the given function to pre-process the objects to compare. And as your function is `i -> i`, the values to compare are not pre-processed at all.

Comment: what do you mean about not pre processed?

Comment: To shorten the discussion: You used an example too complex for beginners, the code to get the maximum value from a stream of int can be written as `ints.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();` - maybe this will help you understand more as it doesn't contain any lambda but a provided function to compare.