# For Loop with Lambda Expression in JAVA

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

Why when I use following code I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Code:

```
    List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(21,22,32,42,52).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.print("the list: ");
    ints.forEach((i) -> {
        System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");
    });
```

My error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    at Agent.lambda$main$1(Agent.java:33)
    at Agent$$Lambda$8/980546781.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1234)
    at Agent.main(Agent.java:32)
the list: Java Result: 1
```

but When I change my list to one digit numbers everything is fine

Code:

```
    List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(2,8,7,4,3).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.print("the list: ");
    ints.forEach((i) -> {
        System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");
    });
```

output:

```
2 8 7 4 3
```

Comment: Something's wrong, because *both* of those snippets cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on my computer.

Comment: What is `i` in the lambda? What does `ints.get(..)` do?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i am not sure cuz I am playing to figure it out them, but as far as I know i is function and return is ints.get() function

Comment: @KickButtowski Translate the lambda to a "regular" loop and you'll see why

Comment: @user3580294 how I gonna see it? why?

Comment: The `(i)` is the value, not the index of the value.  You have using the value as an index to lookup another value, which is a great way to confuse yourself but rarely useful.

Comment: @PeterLawrey hi peter, i know that but as you see I used get to have access to my element in my list

Comment: @KickButtowski I know you did, and this is your problem.  You are trying to access the 12th element of a list which does how have 12 elements.

Comment: It seems to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242352). At the first glance you are failing to simply use the provided list element because you are using the element as an index. But why did you come to the idea of needing an index access and why are you accessing using `i-1`? Did you want access the predecessor? But why, when you are iterating over *all* values? Accessing the predecessor of the first element would break as well, even if `i` was an index rather than an element. So what’s the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [for loop using lambda expression in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399181/for-loop-using-lambda-expression-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason is pretty clear.

```
ints.forEach((i) -> {
    System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");
});
```

Translates approximately to:

```
for (Integer i : ints) {
    System.out.println(ints.get(i - 1) + " ");
}
```

Which will cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s because `i` refers to the **elements** of each list, and each of those elements - 1 will give an index that is *clearly* out of bounds. For your first example, `i` will be `21`, which gives an index of `21 - 1 == 20`, which is out of bounds for the list you created.

Example:

```
List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(21,22,32,42,52).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

will end up so that

```
ints == [21, 22, 32, 42, 52]
```

So when you run this:

```
ints.forEach((i) -> {
    System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");
});
```

The computer takes the first **element** and tries to execute the body of the lambda:

```
Execute System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");:
    First element is 21
    21 - 1 == 20
    ints.get(20) --> IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

And for your second example:

```
List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(2,8,7,4,3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

becomes

```
ints == [2, 8, 7, 4, 3]
```

So when you run this:

```
ints.forEach((i) -> {
    System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");
});
```

The computer goes through the **elements** and tries to execute the body of the lambda:

```
Execute System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");:
    First element is 2
    2 - 1 == 1
    ints.get(1) --> 8
    Print 8
Execute System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");:
    Second element is 8
    8 - 1 == 7
    ints.get(7) --> IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

---

So evidently the code in your second example is *not* what you actually have. I suspect that the code you actually have is:

```
List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(2,8,7,4,3).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.print("the list: ");
ints.forEach((i) -> {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
                     ^^^^^^^ <-- this is different
});
```

Which is entirely different than what you posted.

Comment: no hold on lemme share the another question I posted

Comment: see everybody says it must be i-1 inside get cuz in java array starts from zero

Comment: @KickButtowski That's just a coincidence because of the value of elements in your list...

Comment: @KickButtowski You're not understanding what I'm saying. You're taking the *elements* of the list and using them as *indices*. It's just coincidence that the elements of that particular list happened to be valid indices, and *as the accepted answer pointed out*, as soon as you have elements which are too large you'll get out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: @KickButtowski Did you try both pieces of code in your question? Because both of those will throw exceptions. The code in your last question *happens* to be OK, but as the accepted answer pointed out, wrong values will throw exceptions

Comment: @KickButtowski What do you mean by "used them separately"?

Comment: i used them in different programs

Comment: @KickButtowski Did you use the *exact* code you posted in a different program?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56369/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-user3580294).

Comment: @kick If you have a list of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and you subtract one from each you get `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. If you then use these as indices to the first list, you get the values `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. But if you have a list `[7, 8, 9, 10]`, and you subtract one from each, so `[6, 7, 8, 9]` and then uses those as indices, you get an index out of bounds since there is no element at index 7 in `[7, 8, 9, 10]`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis could you take a look at this link?      
stackoverflow.com/questions/24399181/…

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes, and you should've understood what we just explained already in the answer there. **The `i` in your lambda is each consecutive element in the underlying `List`.**

Comment: i do not get it but thank you so i let everybody to have fun to vote me down or colse it cuz clearly nobody can understand my confusion

Comment: @kick If you have a list of `[1]`, how many elements are there in the list? What are the max and min indices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56370/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: thank you for trying to help, but I get the different out come in my ide so i will figure it later

Answer (score 7):

Even simpler:

```
String s = Stream.of(21,22,32,42,52)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: throw this exception when I run it

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.stream.Stream.collect
 at addnewlinetotxtfile.AddNewLinetoTxtFile.main(AddNewLinetoTxtFile.java:30)
Java Result: 1

Comment: could you lemme know why?

Comment: This is a NetBeans-related problem, clean and rebuild your project. Also google for `Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type`---you'll get further advice on workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

[`forEach` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) states

> Performs the given action for each element of the Iterable until all
>   elements have been processed or the action throws an exception.

So the `i` in

```
(i) -> {System.out.print(ints.get(i-1) + " ");}
```

is each element in the `List`. If any of those elements minus 1 is bigger or equal to 5 (the size of the `List`), you try to get an element that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

You are overdoing it. What you want is

```
List<Integer> ints = Stream.of(2,8,7,4,3).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.print("the list: ");
ints.forEach((i) -> {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
});
```

`i` in the forEach is not a loop counter, it's the items themselves. So `i` will take on the values 2,8,7,4,3 and for the second iteration `ints.get (8-1)` will be out of bounds.