# min/max lambda expression in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, lambda, min

Is there an (elegant) way to define a min/max lambda expression?

```
public class MathFunction{
  private java.util.function.Function <double[], Double> function = null; 
  public MathFunction ( Function <double[], Double> pFunction ){    
     this.function = pFunction;   
  }
}
// now defining a min-function...
MathFunction func = new MathFunction((x) -> min(x));
```

Of course `min(x)` does **not** work. I need a way to sort an array "on the fly".

Comment: Probable duplicate: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378646/finding-max-with-lambda-expression-in-java?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could stream the array and extract the `min` from it:

```
MathFunction func = 
    new MathFunction((x) -> Arrays.stream(x).min().getAsDouble());
```

Comment: Perfect!! I've already tried `Arrays.stream` but did not know about that `.getAsDouble()`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1511417 - There's also `Arrays.stream(x).summaryStatistics()` from which you can pull `getMin()` and `getMax()` and so only traversing the ayrray once.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon cool, didn't know about that. Note that you'd be performing five calculations for each item in the array instead of just one that `min` does. For large arrays this may be a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Mureinik - `min` would still have to perform a complete pass of the array. If you need both `min` and `max` (as OP seems to) the this trick would ensure one pass and deliver both at once.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon agreed - if you need multiple answers, it's best to traverse the list only once. If you only need `min`, though, it's a shame to have to calculate a bunch of other things.